# triggering function on order status change with information from product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Im trying to trigger function with some information from product (like title, attributes ect.) on order status change, but Im getting this error:

```
FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_title() on null
```

Im using this code as my function:

```
function trigerinam_i_duombaze($order_id) {

    global $product;

    $pavadinimas = $product->get_title();

        $sql = "INSERT INTO garantiniai (kompiuterio_bukle, preke, uzsakymo_bukle)
        VALUES ('bukle', $pavadinimas, 'processing')";
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'trigerinam_i_duombaze', 10, 1);
```

I have same `global $product;` and `$pavadinimas = $product->get_title();` used in my other functions without any problems, any Ideas why this not working specifically with this one?

I also tried a bit different function with

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'trigerinam_i_duombaze', 99, 3 );
```

But I'm stuck at exactly same place.. seems like `global $product` is not getting defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access `global $product;` inside `woocommerce_order_status_changed` or `woocommerce_order_status_processing`.

> using `woocommerce_order_status_changed` action hook parameter
> `$order_id, $status_from, $status_to, $order`

```
function trigerinam_i_duombaze_changed( $order_id, $status_from, $status_to, $order) {

    // get order from order id
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); 

    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {

        $pavadinimas = $item->get_name(); 
         
        $sql = "INSERT INTO garantiniai (kompiuterio_bukle, preke, uzsakymo_bukle)
        VALUES ('bukle', $pavadinimas, 'processing')";
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'trigerinam_i_duombaze_changed', 99, 4 );
```

> using `woocommerce_order_status_changed` action hook parameter
> `$order_id, $order`

```
function trigerinam_i_duombaze_processing( $order_id, $order) {

    // get order from order id
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); 

    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {

        $pavadinimas = $item->get_name(); 
         
        $sql = "INSERT INTO garantiniai (kompiuterio_bukle, preke, uzsakymo_bukle)
        VALUES ('bukle', $pavadinimas, 'processing')";
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'trigerinam_i_duombaze_processing', 10, 2);
```

Comment: You're the best! Works like a charm, thank you!

Comment: Welcome... glad to be of help.